# ¿como leer una linea despues de la actual en un txt en python?

Tags: python, txt, salto-de-linea

Tengo un problema, en un archivo .txt tengo los datos de una persona, y segun el nombre el programa debe imprimir el numero de telefono, el cual esta dos lineas mas abajo, y no encuentro como lograrlo, hasta el momento la funcion va asi

```
def BuscarNom():
   Datos = input('Digite el nombre y el apellido de la persona  buscar el numero:')
   f=open('agenda.txt', 'r')
   for linea in f:
       if linea == Datos+'\n':
           cel=linea+2
           print('El telefono de',Datos,'es:',str(cel))
```

No se que debo poner entre la 5ta y sexta linea para que detecte lo que contiene el archivo 2 lineas mas abajo, se que linea no es int y genera error pero es c¿para dar una idea de lo que busco, Muchas gracias

Comment: Una forma mejor de hacerlo es usando la fu con `readlines()` que devuelve una lista y luego de buscar el nombre coger el dato que está 2 posiciones a lado del nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Había una pregunta muy similar pero me dio pereza buscarla y como la respuesta es fácil te la daré. Puede hacer la lectura con `readlines()` lo que devuelve una lista, solo buscamos el nombre dentro de esa lista y luego avanzamos 2 posiciones a la derecha para acceder al numero. Suponiendo que tu `.txt` sea así:

```
Jose
nose
numero
Pedro
nose2
numPedro
```

Para leer el archivo vamos a usar la sentencia `with` así nos ahorramos la tarea de cerrar el fichero.

```py
def BuscarNom():
   Datos = input('Digite el nombre y el apellido de la persona  buscar el numero:')
    with open("texto.txt","r") as f:
        data = f.readlines() #leemos cada linea, devuelve una lista
        data = [d.split()[0] for d in data] #quitamos los saltos de linea

    #cogemos el numero solo si coincide con lo ingresado en Datos
    numero = [data[data.index(n)+2] for n in data[::3] if n == Datos]
    print(numeto[0]) #esto dara error si no se encuentra
    #para evitar el error basta con un if o un try/except
```

Lo interesante viene acá `numero = [data[data.index(n)+2] for n in data[::3] if n == Datos]` aquí le decimos que itere en la lista de `datos` y que verifique si el dato (variable `n`) es igual a lo ingresado, en caso ser asi, vamos a obtener su índice en la lista con `datos.index(n)` y luego le sumamos 2 (`+2`) para acceder al numero. La notación `datos[::3]` indica que cogeremos el dato saltando de 3 en 3, ósea solo los nombres, esto se hace para simplificar la búsqueda.